# Protocol-Buffers C++ can't set variables

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I'm new to C++ (and programming overall). Trying to understand protobuf and have some issues.
Here is the proto file:

```
syntax="proto3";

message FullName{
    string Surname = 1;
    string Name = 2;
    optional string Patronymic = 3;
}

message Student{
    FullName sName = 1;
    repeated int32 Grade = 2;
    int32 AverageMark = 3;
}

message StudentsGroup{
    repeated Student sInfo = 1;
}
```

and here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Students.pb.h"

int average(const google::protobuf::RepeatedField<int32_t>& grades)
{
    int32_t s = 0;
    for (const int& i : grades)
    {
        s = s + i;
    }
    return s/grades.size();
}


int main()
{
    FullName name1;
    name1.set_surname("Sergeev");
    name1.set_name("Sergey");
    name1.set_patronymic("Sergeevich");
    std::cout << name1.name() << std::endl;

    Student student1;
    student1.set_name(name1);  // <--
    student1.add_grade(4);
    student1.add_grade(3);
    student1.set_averagemark(average(student1.grade()));

    StudentsGroup group1;
    group1.add_sinfo(student1);  // <--

}
```

The issue is I don't know how to set student1 sName and add sInfo in group1. The syntax I use is incorrect.
Please help)

Comment: I'm confused. You say you don't know how to set the value of a variable, but you are doing just that in the code provided. Are you getting an error? If so, what error? There needs to be more information provided.

Comment: Explicit 'optional' labels are disallowed in the Proto3 syntax. To define 'optional' fields in Proto3, simply remove the 'optional' label, as fields are 'optional' by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Student` has no `Name` field, thus `Student::set_name()` cannot be available.
2. `Student` has `FullName sName`, `FullName` is not a base type, thus the setter is `Student::set_allocated_sname(::FullName* sname)`.
3. `Student sInfo = 1` is repeated values of not a base type in `StudentsGroup`, thus it should be accessed through the mutable collection `::google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField<::Student>* StudentsGroup::mutable_sinfo()`

The fix:

```
auto name1 = std::make_unique<FullName>();
name1->set_surname("Sergeev");
name1->set_name("Sergey");
name1->set_patronymic("Sergeevich");
std::cout << name1->name() << std::endl;

auto student1 = std::make_unique<Student>();
student1->set_allocated_sname(name1.release());
student1->add_grade(4);
student1->add_grade(3);
student1->set_averagemark(average(student1->grade()));

StudentsGroup group1;
group1.mutable_sinfo()->AddAllocated(student1.release());
```

Comment: And how am I supposed to cout all of the students info from the StudentsGroup variable? Could you please enlighten me)

Comment: Use `group1.sinfo()` in a range-for-loop.